# Excel formula with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to tell certain combinations of genes that make bacteria species.

So:

```
sample number, gene A, gene B, gene C.
```

The formula should be:

- If all 3 are negative then it is a rest group
- If A and B are positive it is bacterial strain Pn
- If A and C are positive it is bacterial strain Ps

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How is your table layout like? And what happens if A, B and C are positive? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 2):

This forumula does it, although I've made some assumptions based upon your post!

```
  =IF(AND(B1<0,C1<0,D1<0),"Rest",IF(AND(B1>=0,C1>=0,D1<0),"Pn",IF(AND(B1>=0,C1<0,D1>=0),"Ps","")))
```

[image]

Stick the forumula into the first row, then drag down the full length of the table.

Comment: Good, simple answer. Also, sorry about the mix up on my [suggested edit](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/154873). A moderator edited the post before the edit was approved, which removed a lot of the text and made my edit look different than intended.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different approach convert your data into an Excel Table (this allows for easier data maintenance and analysis).  Then, assuming the following table:

[image: bacteria species]

Use the following function for your bac_sp column:

> =IF(AND(SIGN([gene a])=-1,SIGN([gene b])=-1,SIGN([gene c])=-1),"Rest",IF(AND(SIGN([gene a])=1,SIGN([gene b])=1,SIGN([gene
>   c])=-1),"Pn",IF(AND(SIGN([gene a])=1,SIGN([gene b])=-1,SIGN([gene
>   c])=1),"Ps","")))

Using the table allows better name usage (e.g. [gene a] rather than B2) and usage of the sign function prevents the need for explicit greater/less than comparisons.  You can also create Pivot Tables based upon this and get some basic stats like count of each type of strain.

**EDIT:**  To avoid a misunderstanding regarding the above function, please review the [Excel function Sign](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sign-function-HP010342898.aspx).  This function simply evaluates whether a particluar value is positive, negative or zero and returns 1,-1, or 0 respectively.  So, it doesnt' matter what the coded value is, simply whether it's positive or negative.  Here's a sample with more diverse sample data (and the same bac_sp formula):

[image: additional example]

As you can see, the results are the same, regardless of the coded values in the gene columns.  The function's arguments of -1, 1 are based upon the possible return values of the Sign function, not based upon the values in the data table.

Comment: This isn't good - what happens if the value was -2? By hard coding actual values into the Excel sheet like this, you've made it impossible to update.

Comment: This doesn't look for the coded value, rather it looks at the value's sign (see Excel Sign function), which returns -1 for negative, 1 for positive (and 0 for 0).  So, it evaluates solely whether a number is negative or positive, regardless of its value.

Comment: I had no idea. This is great. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would use this if you have the genes are in column A, B and C respectively and starting on row 1:

```
=CHOOSE(SUM((A1<=0)*1,(B1<=0)*2,(C1<=0)*4,1),"","","Ps","Pn","","","","Rest")
```

It basically checks for the sign of each cell's and multiplies them by a specific number.

If all are negative, `SUM` returns 8 so that `Rest` is picked.

If A and B are positive, we get a sum of 5, hence `Pn`.

If A and C are positive, we get a sum of 3, hence `Ps`.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like this gives a false Pn result if A and B are negative and C is positive. Also, you're correct, it needs an IFError wrapper for all positive, otherwise it returns #Value!.

Comment: @dav Fixed both issues without `IFERROR()`. I just didn't evaluate all the combinations. Did them now.